# reading multi columns table with out x column

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a table (10000 rows and 14 cols) in a ascii file, which contain only the y - components.

In my case the x's values are 1 till 10000.

Is it possible to tell Tikz to plot from a table only with the y-component? I am aware of `x expr=\coordindex`, but then i need to import each column separately using addplot (in my case 14 times) and i need to define the color of each column separately.

Is there an elegant solution to read the table, use the position of the y value as x position and different color for each column?

Answer (score 3):

You can extract the number of columns using `\pgfplotsgetcolsof{<table macro or file name>}`, and then loop over the columns using `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` (which is similar to TikZ' `\foreach`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableread{
Y1  Y2  Y3  Y4
1   2   2   5
1   3   7   1
8   2   3   1
9   5   3   6
}\datatable

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymin=0]
\pgfplotstablegetcolsof{\datatable}
\pgfmathsetmacro\numberofycols{\pgfplotsretval-1}
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach {0,...,\numberofycols}{
    \addplot table [x expr=\coordindex, y index=#1] {\datatable};
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: how would this solution be change if i read the table from a file?

Comment: i would like to generate legend as well. How could i do it?

Comment: @Eagle: Just change the `pgfplotstableread` line to read from your file.  As for the legend part, that's a separate question I think.  Try some `\addlegendentry`s as the documentation explains.